# Should [figs] and [ficus] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think merging [figs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figs) and [ficus](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ficus) tags could be considered. Although I do not know which one should be kept.

Where I live *Ficus* is the most commonly used name when it comes to various species. We even use *Ficus* in the common name of *Ficus lyrata* as well.

As far as I can tell people use *Ficus* more often in the USA, Canada or UK as well with an exception for *Ficus lyrata*. (At least for the most common houseplant varieties and species.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ficus is the genus name.  The questions tagged Figs are aimed at Ficus carica, the edible species of fig.  We would loose context by merging the two although I am not in favour of species tags as if it was applied uniformly tags would be unusable.

We could create a tag synonym of Ficus carica <=> Figs but I am not sure what value it would have.

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: I see although the excerpt for figs is "Common name for *Ficus* a genus of woody trees, shrubs, vines, epiphytes, and hemiepiphytes." that is why I thought it is for the genus as well.

Comment: Good answer; Retaining the two tags separately is advantageous; also, creating the additional synonym seems unnecessary. Thank you